# Cursor key arrows not functioning in SBT 0.13.* . Suspect Jline. How to enable them?

Tags: windows, scala, sbt, jline

SBT-0.7.7 had JLine bundled in the launcher and it works OK. E.g.:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe"  -jar C:\scala\sbt-launch-0.7.7.jar
```

I can use cursor keys to navigate the command history. It does not work in SBT-0.13.5:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe"  -jar C:\scala\sbt_launch_135.jar
```

When I press cursor keys, printable characters appear instead, like "pHpP". In the target/.history file we see character codes to be "0xE0 0x48 0xE0 0x50". It is the same in Java8 and in 64-bit Java. I also tried various versions of SBT launcher and various values for **jline.terminal** like *-Djline.terminal=jline.AnsiWindowsTerminal* to no avail. I also tried *-Djline.WindowsTerminal.directConsole=false* -- then cursor keys perform no function at all. In all cases I can use <kbd>CTRL+P</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL+N</kbd> to navigate the history.

SBT-0.13.* loads JLine from an Ivy repository *%HOMEPATH%.sbt\boot\scala-2.10.3\org.scala-sbt\sbt\0.13.1\jline-2.11.jar* I inspected the source code of JLine. Version 2.10.3 has a primitive configuration file **keybindings.properties** and function **readVirtualKey()** in **WindowsTerminal.java** handles the cursor keys. All versions of JLine install a helper DLL in a temporary directory like *%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Temp\jline_.dll*, which presumably works.

Why is it not working correctly? How to make the cursor keys work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try passing following property to sbt process, i.e.:

```
sbt -Dinput.encoding=Cp1252
```

as mentioned [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/880)